# How to use the same Database when updating CoreDataStack

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, appdelegate

I am updating my `CoreDataStack` in my `appDelegate`. However when doing do I seem to lose/ not be using the same database as the original stack. The database Is on the persistent store and I did not change the sqlite url when updating the stack.

```
self.storeDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
```

Here's the original stack;

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("APPNAME", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as! NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

**New CoreDataStack**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.setupCoreData()

    try! managedObjectContext.save()

    // Setup Ensemble
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("APPNAME", withExtension: "momd")
    cloudFileSystem = CDEICloudFileSystem(ubiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)

    ensemble = CDEPersistentStoreEnsemble(ensembleIdentifier: "APPNAME", persistentStoreURL: storeURL, managedObjectModelURL: modelURL!, cloudFileSystem: cloudFileSystem)
    ensemble.delegate = self


}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

var storeDirectoryURL: NSURL {
    return try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
}

var storeURL: NSURL {
    return self.storeDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
}

func setupCoreData() {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("APPNAME", withExtension: "momd")
    let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)

    try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(self.storeDirectoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model!)
    let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    try! coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: self.storeURL, options: options)

    managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

}
```

Where am I going wrong ? I need to use the database from the original stack. The answer is most likely obvious, I am new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with initializing the base directory.

Original:

```
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
```

New:

```
return try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.ApplicationSupportDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true) }
```

In original stack you are using documents directory and in new you are using support directory.